# Incorrect calculation in groovy - float and round

Tags: groovy

I am having difficulty with a math equation in groovy and want to know how to fix it.

Basically I have 5 string values I convert into float,

```
5.00
26.00
0
52.48
-100
```

The answer to this should be -121.48 if I type this in the calculator but instead in my code I am getting -100.21. Where am i going wrong with my float and rounding?

```
Math.round(Float.valueOf((String) '5.00') 
           + Float.valueOf((String) '26.00') 
           + Float.valueOf((String) '0') 
           - Float.valueOf((String) '52.48') 
           + Float.valueOf( (String) '-100') * 100) / 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put a brackets before multiplying by `100`

```
//(all addition and subtraction) * 100 / 100

Math.round((Float.valueOf((String) '5.00') 
       + Float.valueOf((String) '26.00') 
       + Float.valueOf((String) '0') 
       - Float.valueOf((String) '52.48') 
       + Float.valueOf( (String) '-100')) * 100) / 100
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I should have formatted it as how you formatted it and then I would have been able to see the missing bracket myself

Comment: a piece of advice, try coding with proper *formatting/indentation*. This is one of the best practice that's strictly maintained in industry level.